# Calling Firebase as On Click with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, html-lists

I'm new to Js, JQuery and Firebase, I went through every online tutorial I could find and thought I had figured it out. I thought I'd try making a simple dictionary app - not so simple.

What I want to happen is: On click go to page (#uib_define_3) and show the title and definitions. Is this even possible? I ended up slapping together a bunch of code that looked like it would work. I'm not even sure what I did wrong/right.

I appreciate the help in advance and if you could write your answer as Absolute Basic Instructions, I'd appreciate that more.

**List View**

```
<div class="widget uib_w_2 ui-content no_wrap outset-margin d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listview" data-ver="0">
<ul data-role="listview">
<li class="widget uib_w_3" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-role="list-divider"><span>A</span>
</li>
<li class="widget uib_w_4" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-icon="false" data-ver="0" id="1"><a href="#uib_define_3"><span>A day late</span></a>
</li>
<li class="widget uib_w_5" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-icon="false" data-ver="0" id="2"><a href="#uib_define_3"><span>A dollar short </span></a>
</li>
<li class="widget uib_w_6" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-icon="false" data-ver="0" id="1"><a href="#uib_define_3"><span>A dose of hike </span></a>
</li> 
</div>
```

**J**

```
booksref = new Firebase("https://dicofwood.firebaseio.com/book/terms")

// ...Get the data from the inputs...
  findtitle = $("#findtitle").val()
  finddefine = $("#finddefine").val()

document.write(snapshot.key('title'));
document.write(snapshot.key('define'));
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-container">
<div id="title">document.querySelector('#title').text</div>
</div>
</div>
<span class="uib_shim"></span>
</div>
</div>
<span class="uib_shim"></span>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_5 row-height-5" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
<div class="col uib_col_5 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
<div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
<div class="tarea widget uib_w_67 d-margins" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0" name="uib_w_67">
<div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
<div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
<div class="w3-card">
<p>(“define”)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused at what behaviour you are trying to accomplish?  Is it that you want to execute a firebase query on click?  What does your firebase data look like?  I don't see any sort of query being built, so I don't know what you've tried.

Comment: I apologies, it seems I'm way over my head with this.  This is supposed to be a dictionary app. If I could please ask for your help @OzBarry. I want to be able call the "id", "define" and "title. The database is set up as: dicofwood
--------------book
----------------------terms                                                                                 ------------------------------id: 0
------------------------------define: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
------------------------------title: A day late.

Comment: If you are new to javascript (or programming in general?), you may want to work on a simpler project. If you want to stick with this, trim it down to be simpler. For instance, a table (or nested lists) with all your dictionary data.  Once you understand how to get and set data to firebase in javascript, I think the rest might just fall into place. This seems like it might be a work project, so I don't know if I can do your job for you. If you already understand how to interact with firebase, then this is a jQuery question, and you should check google for some jQuery tutorials.